# Does functools.wraps have the undecorated reference?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from functools import wraps
def logged(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print func.__name__ + " was called"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_logging

@logged
def f(x):
   """does some math"""
   return x + x * x
```

I want to know if `wraps` has the undecorated reference to the function f? I don't see it when I tried `dir(f)`

---

Modified version

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from functools import wraps
def logged(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print func.__name__ + " was called"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    with_logging.undecorated = func
    return with_logging

@logged
def f(x):
   """does some math"""
   return x + x * x

f.undecorated
```

No attribute? I was merely following what I used to do with decorator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reference to the original `f` in there, but it's messy to get to.

```
>>> f
<function f at 0x023F6DF0>
>>> f.func_closure[0].cell_contents
<function f at 0x023F6E30>
```

The first is the wrapped `f`, the second is the original `f`, notice the hex addresses are different.

If you need access to the original `f`, I suggest you wrap it differently:

```
def f(x):
   """does some math"""
   return x + x * x
original_f = f
f = logged(f)
```

Now you have `f` and `original_f`, both usable.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about `func_closure` too but I wouldn't get that right... Thanks for the alternate solution. Why wouldn't my modified version work? It said `f.undecorated` does not have that attribute. How come?

Comment: Your updated code works for me on 2.7: `f.undecorated` has the original function.

Comment: It'd be nice to standardize on `wrapped` or `__wrapped__`, say.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Hmmm weird. It doesn't work for me on 2.6.5. I will test more, thanks.

Comment: @ecatmur What do you mean standardize? Thanks.

Comment: @user1012451 Well, e.g. the `decorator.decorator` decorator exposes the underlying function through the `__wrapped__` attribute; it'd be great if decorators in general behaved the same way: http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#getting-the-source-code

Answer (score 2):

You can access the original function by calling:

`f.__wrapped__()`

where f is the function that you are decorating